# Запятая перед И

Tags: запятая

Здравствуйте! Объясните, пожалуйста постановку запятой перед "И". Нужна ли она здесь: "И веселая эта книга, и грустная"? Т.к. встречала разные вариации: "Павлику было и смешно и неловко..." (Г. Адамов. Тайна двух океанов), "Ей и смешно и противно стало" (А.Г. Малышкин.  Люди из захолустья), "Следует взять его в руки. И смешно, и грустно!" (З.Н. Гиппиус. Мисс Май), "Горичу сделалось и смешно, и жалко" (А. Н. Апухтин. Неоконченная повесть).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Однородные члены предложения, соединенные повторяющимися союзами, разделяются запятой. Запятая может не ставиться, если однородные члены представляют собой тесное единство. Есть это самое единство или нет его - кто может оценить? Чаще всего только автор высказывания. Есть перечислительная интонация - ставим запятую, нет - не ставим.  В вашем случае единства нет. Его разрушает определяемое существительное, которое стоит между однородными определениями. Запятая нужна.

Comment: Большое спасибо, что помогли.